# Show that x is a point of closure of E if and only if there is a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

How do I start the proof of the following statement?

$x$ is a point of the closure of $E$ if and only if there is a sequence $\{y_n\} \subset E$ with $x = \lim_{n\to +\infty} y_n$.

I thought about trying to go about using metric spaces but im not sure?

Comment: Hint: If $x$ is in the closure of $E$, then every open neighborhood of $x$ intersects with $E$. What does that mean in a metric space. Also, ask yourself what it means for $x$ to be the limit of the sequence $y_n$.

Comment: Hint: Consider balls of radius $\frac{1}{n}$ for example. What happens in every ball centered in that point of closure?

Comment: I feel like I need to start off with the statement $x \in E$ closed$\implies n \in  \mathbb{N}  $ and $x \in B(x,1/n)$ thus I can show $B(x,1/n) \cap E \neq \phi $ so we can get $y_n \in  B(x,1/n) \cap E$. But not sure about the logic behind finishing the proof. Metric spaces are sort of a new concept to me but im starting to get the hang of it. Hopefully .